# How can I make an absolute path for an specific file?

Tags: php, path, routes

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo __DIR__."/../css/styles-home.css";
?>
```

It prints:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\ltk\application/../css/styles-home.css
```

While this is the expected result:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\ltk/css/styles-home.css
```

How can I get that ^ ?

Comment: [realpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: I've tried that, but still the same result.

Comment: Define a constant which defines your webroot, then use it throughout your app.

Comment: You have to include the step up "../" in with `realpath()`, if it is in the string appended after, it will still just print the step up instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are just echo-ing the file path, the "../" isn't going to take you one step up in your directories, it's just going to print the "../". To go up one step, use the following code inline with your echo statement:

For PHP 5.3+ use:

```
echo realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')."/css/styles-home.css";
```

Or in PHP < 5.3 use:

```
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..')."/css/styles-home.css";
```

Comment: Thank you .. Now the problem is, that css file will not be open with that path. Noted that the path is right, since when I paste it into browser, it will be opened. Any idea?

Comment: What code are you using to try to open the file in PHP?

Comment: Here is my code: `<link href="<?=realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')?>/css/styles-home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: `<link href="<?php echo realpath(__DIR__.'/..'); ?>/css/styles-home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` This code seems to work for me. I changed the php start definition and added `echo`.